# AutoCompleteBox dropdown list shows only class name

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, autocompletebox

I'm trying to use `AutoCompleteBox` in my program, but something unwanted happens when I run the application. The problem is that dropdown list of filtered elements shows only name of binded class. When I click on any element, correct value in `AutoCompleteBox` is set.

Example:

[image]

`View`

```
<controls:AutoCompleteBox Grid.Column="0"
                          Grid.Row="5"
                          Margin="1"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding RadiatoryComboBoxItem}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRadiator, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          ValueMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"
                          ValueMemberPath="Value"
                          Text="{Binding SelectedRadiator}" />
```

`ViewModel`

```
public IQueryable<ComboBoxKeyAndValue> RadiatoryComboBoxItem
{
    get
    {
        return
        (
            from value in tetraEntities.Radiatory
            select new ComboBoxKeyAndValue
            {
                Key = value.idRadiator,
                Value = value.nameRadiator
            }
        ).ToList().AsQueryable();
     }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: I've got an error: "A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'ValueMemberPath' property of type 'AutoCompleteBox'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject".

Comment: I'm sorry try settting `ValueMemberPath="Value"`

Comment: I've already tried this, but unfortunately it changed nothing...

Comment: Can you edit that into your question? You will need that regardless.

Comment: `Text="{Binding SelectedRadiator.Value}"`?

Comment: Modifying text binding gives no difference.

Comment: Another dirty way of doing this is to **ovveride** `ToString()` method for your `ComboBoxKeyAndValue` class.

Comment: Thank you, now it works. Unfortunately, I encountered another problem. When I select value from AutoCompleteBox and this value has such symbols as "+", "-", "\" etc. after clicking on another controls like TextBox, cursor in ACB goes to the new line and value "disappers". As a result, user might think, the value has not been chosen yet. Is it any solution to solve this (I would not like to make AutoCompleteBox higher).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. All what I've done was overriding method ToString() in my class which was binded as a ItemSource.